# How to skip levels in a TikZ graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

In the following simple graph drawn with the TikZ `\graph` command I would like the red **f** node to appear on the same level as the other leaf nodes (**a**, **b**, **c**, **d**). Is there any option to skip a level between **C** and **f**?

[image]

The respective code (compile with `lualatex`):

```
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\RequirePackage{luatex85}}{}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{trees,layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [grow down, layered layout] { 
      A -> {B ->{D, E}, C},
      D -> {a, b},
      E -> {c, d},
      C -> {f[red]}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know to answer your question but would like to mention that, if you were drawing this with forest, you could immediately achieve this with `tier`.

Comment: I finally found it... `> minimum layers=2` is one option, `{[same layer] d, f}` is another one.

Comment: Congratulations! I couldn't make the `same layer` work. I am wondering if you want to post an answer yourself, I certainly would upvote it.

Comment: @marmot: Sure, was already preparing the answer :-)

Comment: And I upvoted accordingly. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The TikZ manual has become overwhelming and sometimes you have to read a chapter the third time to eventually find the option you have been looking for...

In my case they are even two of them, described in §30 *Graph Drawing Algorithms: Layered Layouts*.

Variant 1 skips one layer with `[> minimal layers=2]`:

```
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\RequirePackage{luatex85}}{}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{trees,layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [grow down, layered layout] { 
      A -> {B ->{D, E}, C},
      D -> {a, b},
      E -> {c, d},
      C -> {f[red, > minimum layers=2]}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Variant 2 uses the `[same layer]` option that can be passed late to a graph:

```
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\RequirePackage{luatex85}}{}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{trees,layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [grow down, layered layout] { 
      A -> {B ->{D, E}, C},
      D -> {a, b},
      E -> {c, d},
      C -> {f[red]};
      {[same layer] d, f};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 , Welcome to the tikz world xD

Comment: @JLeonV. The freaking thing is that I have been using TikZ for ... probably ten years. But anyway, eventually there always is a solution.